# How Kotlin infers Java method parameter nullability?

Tags: java, kotlin, null

I'm trying to call Java method `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update#set` from Kotlin code. This method is declared as

```java
public Update set(String key, Object value)
```

There is no additional annotations or comments about parameters nullability. In fact, it just puts `value` into `HashMap`, so effectively `value` might be `null`.

However, Kotlin compiler treats `value` type as `Any` (instead of expected `Any!`), and fails when passing `null` with

```
Null can not be a value of a non-null type Any
```

Passing nullable value with `!!` patently causes `KotlinNullPointerException`, casting `as Any` throws `TypeCastException`.

What is the logic behind such nullability inference? Passing `null` parameter with reflection actually works well, but is there more natural solution?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/004e8ba0ea1d4cb1d6dcd52e7237143f553cac89/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Update.java#L117

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is caused by the annotation in [the package's `package-info.java`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/004e8ba0ea1d4cb1d6dcd52e7237143f553cac89/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/):

```
@org.springframework.lang.NonNullApi
package org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query;
```

which is

> [A common Spring annotation to declare that parameters and return values are to be considered as non-nullable by default for a given package... used by Kotlin to infer nullability of Spring API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/lang/NonNullApi.html)